# How to use BFS to find shortest path in 6x6 grid maze C#

Tags: c#, text-files, breadth-first-search, maze

I've seen similar question has been asked many times here, I tried to use them but couldn't understand how it should work in my case. Please help me figure out on how to solve this.

So I have 6 x 6 grid maze reading from text file, and I want to find the shortest way from the beginning to the end, I found on the web it should be done using bfs algorithm however Idk how to implement that. Here's my code.

```
class Program
{    
    static char dottozero(char a)
    {
        a = 'O';
        return a;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[,] Tablero = new char[6, 6];    
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("maze.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Tablero[i, j] = lines[i][j];

                if ((int)Tablero[i, j] == (int)'.' || (int)Tablero[i, j] == (int)'B' || 
                    (int)Tablero[i, j] == (int)'E')
                {
                        Tablero[i, j] = dottozero(Tablero[i, j]);
                }

                Console.Write(Tablero[i, j]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();    
    }
}
```

And my maze looks like this, 'X' are walls, dots are free road, 'B' is beginning point and 'E' endpoint

```
Bxxxxx
.....x
x.xx.x
x....x
x.xxxx
x....E
```

passed way should be printed as O instead of dots, So I if bfs is correct algorithm for my case the output should be like this ?

```
Oxxxxx
OO...x
xOxx.x
xO...x
xOxxxx
xOOOOO
```

Comment: Not a stack overflow question. Sounds like homework . but basically, paint from start point and go on. I'm sure wiki can give you that.

Comment: Instead of a method that simply returns a `0`, it would be simpler to just do `Tablero[i,j] = '0';`

Comment: What specifically is the issue you're having? What is the problem with your current code? Your question is far too broad as it stands right now.

Comment: To make it [mcve] please put the maze data into `Tablero` and not in a file. What is wrong with the output you get ?

Comment: Your code does not do dfs. All it does is replacing all chars but 'x` to 'o`

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not do [dfs](http://www.koderdojo.com/blog/depth-first-search-algorithm-in-csharp-and-net-core). All it does is replacing all chars but `x`  to `o` so the output you should expect for the given input is

> [o, x, x, x, x, x]
>  
>   [o, o, o, o, o, x]
>   [x, o, x, x, o,x]
>  
>   [x, o, o, o, o, x]
>  
>   [x, o, x, x, x, x]
>  
>   [x, o, o, o, o, o]